# How to split audio signal into 3 separate channels?

Tags: audio, circuit-design, signal

I have been working with the following circuit: 
[image]

to build a audio mixer where you can take multiple line inputs, cd players, computer, phone, synthesizers, etc... and mix them together to a single stereo "master" out.

The "master" out can be a power amplifier or powered speakers. So far tested powered speakers and works good and I expect this to work with "professional" grade amplifier/speakers. I.e: Mackies, Adams, Bryston etc... I will test with as much gear I can get my hands on...

So what I want to do is split the "master" out to 3 outputs: master, room and record and each with their own volumes.

1. I'm thinking of taking R8A, R8B (the master POT) and replacing with a regular 22K resistor.
2. Split the stereo signal after R9 and R10 and add 3 22K POTs there
3. Finally line to 3 separate "stereo" jacks/channels

I'm going to do some testing. But I don't have enough gear to test it all, I'm thinking it will be ok so long the input impedance of the destination devices is bigger enough then the total out?

Does my plan sound sane or do you think I should add buffers to each of the split signal?

**Update:**

Pots are log.

Sample impedances:

- http://www.bryston.com/PDF/Manuals/3B_4BSST_MANUAL.pdf 50 Kohms single ended, 20 Kohms balanced
- https://www.adam-audio.com/en/ax-series/a7x/ 30 kOhm
- https://www.zoom-na.com/products/field-video-recording/field-recording/zoom-h4n-handy-recorder 480 kΩ unbalanced

**Update 2**:

Using TL072 as the op-amp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Since users are pretty good at finding the weak point in any design, I'd recommend just using a buffer for each channel (yes that's 6 total opamps but they're cheap). For example, what if a user wants to temporarily disconnect your high impedance equipment to check the sound using their nice low impedance headphones?

2) High output impedance (compared to a low impedance buffered output) will make your transmission line more susceptible to noise, so if you're using high end equipment you're not doing yourself any favors by skimping on the output stage as long as you choose a decent quality opamp.

My recommendation would be to move your master potentiometer to the output of the summing stage (instead of R9 and R10), and splitting that into three different paths to feed each buffer opamp circuit. I think it would be a good idea to put a medium sized resistor (10k??) between the master potentiometer wiper lead and each buffer input too, that way the buffers don't interact with each other.

Comment: Cool! Things to consider. For the headphone I supose, but it's XLR. Not once in my life I ever tried to plug my headphones into the master out of my mixing desk of any kind even using some sort of stereo jack to XLR converter. But I get your point. lol

Comment: Also I don't want the master pot to affect the room. So if you lower the master you can still hear the room and vice versa. Same with record they should simply be separate outputs.

Comment: Ha isn't that the point of a master control though? (It would be a good idea to include it anyways and just not touch it right?) Anyways, in order to get that much control without adding extra opamps, you may want to consider using non-inverting configurations so you can add potentiometers to the inputs without impact the gain settings.

Comment: He, master and room are usually separate volumes. This is common in DJ Mixer. And I just realized I mean to say master/room and booth. Lol

Comment: My design is modular I can put quite a bit of inputs for now doing 4. https://www.instagram.com/p/BzlfgDKnm0o/?igshid=yn9tz6pzfukg Those aren't final pots nor is the master wired yet. Black/green is power the white is the audio. Top right connector is the master out to jacks or it could be another board which can have what is discussed above. Most bottom connectors is where the input jacks will go.

Comment: I chose this answer. I did more reading and voltage follower/buffer is the way to go.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing the picture and good luck with your project! If there's any other tips you'd like me to add to this accepted answer, let me know so it can help others (for example your final decision on the master vs booth potentiometer).

Comment: Here is the project... https://www.instagram.com/p/B0OoaLnHr6k/ Pots or wiring not final, this doesn';t have the buffers yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan sounds fine, although if the output pots are audio taper, they act as an 80% attenuator at 50% rotation - you might need to increase R8 for higher gain to compensate.

Three 22 K pots in parallel present a 7.33 K impedance to the 47 ohm buildout resistors, a ratio of over 150:1, so the loading on the outputs will be minimal.

Depending on the input impedances of the downstream devices and the output pot settings, the load impedance seen by R9 and R10 might be lower, but you would have to have all three pots at max rotation plus three very low input impedance devices for the loading to be significant.

Note that your plan will increase the apparent output impedance of the circuit, again as seen by the downstream devices connected to the output pot wipers.  For example, if an output pot is set at approx.80% rotation (again, audio taper, working from memory), the output impedance will be approx. 11K.  If the target amp has an input impedance of 10 K, this forms a 55% (-6.44 dB) attenuator.  The net effect is that you might find the pots adjusted a bit higher than expected for the same volume as a direct connection to the original circuit.

Comment: I added some sample devices and their impedances to my question. But I think it will be ok. Plus I also expect that each down stream device will be adjusted to the hearing preferences of the user. So for the "master" channel will always the loudest, while "room" less louder for example.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple connect three log volume control potentiometers to an audio preamp IC output and wire the sliders of the pots to the hot pins of the output connectors. Use low resistance, say 2 kOhm potentiometers and be sure your preamp can feed 600 Ohm well. Use stereo pots for 2 channel stereo configuration.

If you need level setting switches or long cable feed (5 meters or more) ability this is too simple.

**ADD:** The cable length limit isn't exact, but unbalanced connections have a tendency to catch noise when cables are long and there's several devices with mains voltage supply connected together. The devices have unwanted secondary connections through their power supplies. TL072 should be able to feed those about 1Vpp or less  signals to 600 Ohm. The devices cause minimal loads.

**ADD2:** Just noticed that you have some serious pro audio stuff. Maybe a redesign with proper balanced signals and surely full audio bandwidth amps is well worth the effort. If you can have $2000,-/pair speakers (and all other devices in the same league) which most hobby musicians can only dream of, do not enter into pauperism just now.

Comment: It can work, but I have found long unbalanced audio connections collect noise if it is available. It surely is available if you have several mains supplied devices. they make unwanted loops via their power supplies. It's a property of unbalanced lines. I guess you have about 100 mV signals and high impedance inputs.

Comment: Also are you saying that after R9 and r10 I should have another op-amp and wire the pots to that?

Comment: I added some sample devices in my question.

Comment: @user432024 no, connect the pots to pins 1 and 7. The other ends can be at GND. Every pot sliding output should have its own safety resistor against short circuits and static electricity.

Comment: The 833 is designed from the ground up to be a preamp.  As such, it has almost no output current capability.  The lowest load impedance for any listed parameter is 2 K, so I don't think it can drive three 2 K pots in parallel very well.  Also, it will drive long cables just fine - the better the shielding, the lower the noise, but that has nothing to do with the chip or circuit configuration.

Comment: Sorry if sounding silly, so to pin 1 and 7 before C7 and C10 or after R9 and R10?

Comment: Ah yes. Another Update I'm using the TL072.

Comment: About the cables and noise - cable noise pickup will be greater than with the original circuit because of the increased output impedance caused by the pots.  How high is too high? - up to you.

Comment: @user432024 pins 1 and 7 are the outputs of the amp ICs, just the left ends of C7 and C10 in your circuit drawing. TL072 can output plusminus 10 V peak to 2 kOhm or more. I guess it can well feed less than 1 V to 600 Ohm. Of course that must be tested before making the final build.

Comment: It's a hobby project, born out of some OCD lol I have decent pro audio gear and it's more for myself type of thing. If I can even accomplish it. So just taking the advice. So I understand about balanced vs unbalanced. I will have multiple iterations. The above circuit is just a module. So I will plan balanced signal at the output stage as I plan to add some other modules after the summing mixer circuit. So now I'm planing the split signal "module"

Comment: @user432024 Ti and Burr-Brown have pro audio quality amp ICs which greatly simplify having clean sounding (=high slew rate, low noise)  balanced inputs and outputs. Check these datasheets http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv135.pdf and http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina137.pdf TL072 isn't especially bad but NE5532 would be better. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532a.pdf. Low noise mic inputs will be a challenge. Something good enough for SM58 which is held near screamer's lips isn't a problem.

Comment: @user432024 (continued) this is a full schematic of pretty good semi pro audio mixer http://thesnowfields.com/manuals/Seck%201282,%201882%20Service%20Manual.pdf It it has single ended outputs only, but it works well with few meter long cables. Its opamp Mic inputs are acceptable for many purposes, but for weak sounds they are too noisy. I guess most people haven't so silent room that the opamp mic inputs become a problem.